# Why is the group's logo displaying "Ops"?

Tags: discussion, bug

Why is our logo displaying "Ops"? Even if there is no place for "DevOps" could be there a better alternative? like "i/o" or some other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beta sites get a 'sketchy' look and feel as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55529/will-all-stack-exchange-sites-look-the-same) and have the opportunity to voice ideas on the theme on graduation of the site.

According to [Are the beta Stack Exchange site logos generated automatically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59502/are-the-beta-stack-exchange-site-logos-generated-automatically) it's a matter of who designed the logo for the beta opening.

It [has already happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130133/different-stack-exchange-sites-have-the-same-logo/130145#130145) two sites got the same "look like" logo.

So for now I'd say it's not really an issue, we will work around this subject with the site design when we will be around 10 question per day, which still needs some effort of publicity for the site at time of writing (roughly 3,5 Q/day and less than 500 visits per day).